# Drone imagery online deaddrop

Tags: images, gis

I have aerial imagery produced using a drone. In my case the images have been processed and are presented as decently georeferenced to geotiffs.

I would like to make the products freely available. The conditions for sharing are more or less as follows:

- License should be copyleft or similar
- The service should facilitate for further georeferencing of the imagery
- I should be able to deposit the imagery anonymously
- It should provide services which make it easy to use the imagery for OpenStreetMap tracing - or other commercial operators for that case.

In my case I have acquired the imagery within the national regulations. For other providers there might still be issues where the formalities of the imagery origins could cause complications - hence the options to deposit imagery anonymously. Such issues could be:

- Political situation
- Unclear/undefined ownership of imagery
- Unclear/undefined legal situation related to the imagery acquisition -

I should of course stress that I am not looking for a "guerrilla" type of service which credits/condones/encourages imagery which implies obvious illegal and/or dangerous operations of drones as part of the raw imagery acquisition.

Are there any services which could be relevant for the above challenge?

Answer (score 1):

[www.openaerialmap.org](http://www.openaerialmap.org) is a clear option. OpenAerialMap is an open service to provide access to a commons of openly licensed imagery and map layer services.